# How to get the Limesurvey API working in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, api, limesurvey

I'm trying to get the session key from the Limesurvey API using Python 2.7 and I'm not getting any results after running my code. I've followed the example in the documentation but still get an error 
`<p>Error: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'></p>`. My code is as follows:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
import sys

req = urllib2.Request(url='https://testone.limequery.com/index.php/admin/remotecontro,\
                              data='{\"method\":\"get_session_key\",\"params\":[\"admin\",\"Password\"],\"id\":1}')
req.add_header('content-type', 'application/json')
req.add_header('connection', 'Keep-Alive')

try:    
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    myretun = f.read()
    j=json.loads(myretun)
    print (j['result'])
except :
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print ( "<p>Error: %s</p>" % e )
```

Removing the try catch gives me the error `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: You're catching all exceptions. Remove the try catch and get the full traceback or add `except e` to the code

Comment: @cricket_007 I removed the try catch and I get the error `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: Please show the output of `myretun` rather than `json.loads(myretun)`

Comment: @cricket_007 `print (myretun)` is empty

Comment: Alright, so you got no data back from the API. And that is probably something worth testing *outside of Python*

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh thanks! I've just realised on the admin page of Limesurvey they turn off API access by default so I've got the code working now. Wish they specify this in the docs as the setting is not very obvious and I been stuck for hours. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There's the [`citric`](https://citric.readthedocs.io) Python library. It abstracts the JSON RPC interface and exposes the RPC methods as methods of the `Client` class.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: I can confirm this works fine, with simple function call, got from example here : https://citric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

"from citric import Client with Client(
    "https://mylimesite.limequery.com/admin/remotecontrol",
    "myusername",
    "mypassword",
) as client:
    for survey in client.list_surveys():
        print(survey["surveyls_title"])